# CASE Statement with multiple outcomes - some outcomes overlooked

Tags: sql, t-sql, case

I have a case statement such as the one below that has multiple outcomes. Unfortunately, due to the first three outcomes being satisfied, the other options are being ignored. Is there some way of the statement considering all outcomes?

```
 ,CASE WHEN T.T1_HoNOSCA_Score IS NULL THEN 'Missing T1'
    WHEN T.T2_HoNOSCA_Score IS NULL THEN 'Missing T2'
    WHEN T.T1HonosValidity IN ('NULL','Invalid 9','Invalid Null') 
    OR T.T2_HonosValidity IN ('NULL','Invalid 9','Invalid Null') THEN 'Invalid Data'
    WHEN T.T1_HoNOSCA_Score IS NULL AND T.T2_HoNOSCA_Score IS NULL THEN 'Missing T1 & T2'   
    WHEN T.T1_HoNOSCA_Score IS NULL AND T.T1HonosValidity IN ('NULL','Invalid 9','Invalid    `enter code here`Null') 
    OR T.T2_HonosValidity IN ('NULL','Invalid 9','Invalid Null') THEN 'Missing T1 & Invalid Data'
    WHEN T.T2_HoNOSCA_Score IS NULL AND T.T1HonosValidity IN ('NULL','Invalid 9','Invalid Null') 
    OR T.T2_HonosValidity IN ('NULL','Invalid 9','Invalid Null') THEN 'Missing T2 & Invalid Data'
    WHEN T.T1_HoNOSCA_Score IS NULL AND T.T2_HoNOSCA_Score IS NULL AND T.T1HonosValidity IN ('NULL','Invalid 9','Invalid Null') 
    OR T.T2_HonosValidity IN ('NULL','Invalid 9','Invalid Null') THEN 'Missing T1 & T2 & Invalid Data'
    ELSE NULL END AS Data_Quality_Type
```

Comment: Please add example data and expected output.

Comment: Change the order of `when..then` clauses so more complex ones come first.

Comment: As soon as the first CASE is satisfied, the others are not even checked. Keep that in mind and re-design your query. Either changing order of clauses - or - using CASEs within the CASE.

Answer (score 2):

Your `CASE` statement contains boolean expressions that are not mutually exclusive. Some of these expressions are stronger than others.

A condition `X` is said to be *stronger* than a condition `Y` if `X` implies `Y`. In other words, `Y` is true every time the `X` is true.

For example, consider two conditions:

```
T.T2_HoNOSCA_Score IS NULL                                -- Condition 1
```

and

```
T.T1_HoNOSCA_Score IS NULL AND T.T2_HoNOSCA_Score IS NULL -- Condition 2
```

Every time condition 2 is satisfied, condition 1 will be satisfied as well, because condition 1 is `AND`-ed with some additional criteria to form condition 2. Therefore, condition 2 is stronger than condition 1.

When you have a case statement with non-mutually exclusive conditions like yours, you need to order them from strongest to weakest. Otherwise, your weaker conditions would "shadow" the stronger ones, never letting them to execute.

Answer (score 1):

you can dissect the case expresssion into a set of 3 individual tests, joining the result as needed.

the example is provided in oracle syntax. however, your dbms will provide similar string formatting functions, otherwise choose the functionally equivalent but less readable version in pure sql.

```
, RTRIM (
     RTRIM (
         SUBSTR(
                CASE WHEN T.T1_HoNOSCA_Score IS NULL THEN ' Missing T1 &'   ELSE '' END
             || CASE WHEN T.T2_HoNOSCA_Score IS NULL THEN ' Missing T2 &'   ELSE '' END
             || CASE WHEN    T.T1_HonosValidity IN ('NULL','Invalid 9','Invalid Null')
                          OR T.T2_HonosValidity IN ('NULL','Invalid 9','Invalid Null')
                                                     THEN ' Invalid Data &' ELSE '' END
           , 2
         )
       , '&'
     )
  )
```

sql:

```
 SUBSTR(
        CASE WHEN T.T1_HoNOSCA_Score IS NULL THEN ' Missing T1 &'   ELSE '' END
     || CASE WHEN T.T2_HoNOSCA_Score IS NULL THEN ' Missing T2 &'   ELSE '' END
     || CASE WHEN    T.T1_HonosValidity IN ('NULL','Invalid 9','Invalid Null')
                  OR T.T2_HonosValidity IN ('NULL','Invalid 9','Invalid Null')
                                             THEN ' Invalid Data &' ELSE '' END
   , 2
   , LENGTH (
            CASE WHEN T.T1_HoNOSCA_Score IS NULL THEN ' Missing T1 &'   ELSE '' END
         || CASE WHEN T.T2_HoNOSCA_Score IS NULL THEN ' Missing T2 &'   ELSE '' END
         || CASE WHEN    T.T1_HonosValidity IN ('NULL','Invalid 9','Invalid Null')
                      OR T.T2_HonosValidity IN ('NULL','Invalid 9','Invalid Null')
                                                 THEN ' Invalid Data &' ELSE '' END
     ) - 3
 )
```